# Problem trying to login to a rest api (nodejs and passport) using react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a backend that uses Node.js and Passport to manage the users.
Using postman I can register user, login, logout... everything works.

Postman Login:

HTTP://localhost:5001/login

```js
{
    "email":"registeredemail@server.com",
    "password":"test"
}
```

Doing that on postman I get the user back as response and its status change on the database from offline to online.

The problem starts when I try to call the login route from the client-side (react)

I am trying now to set up a prototype website to login/register users.

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5001/login', { email: email.value, password: password.value })
```

If I am doing that request from the frontend I get an error on the backend:

```
undefined
(node:17468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

The `req.user` object is undefined

Important is that the backend works when I am using postman.

Backend index.js

```js
router.post('/login', authController.login)
router.get('/auth', userController.SetUserStatus)
```

Backend authController

```js
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        successRedirect: '/auth'
    })
```

Backend userController

```js
exports.SetUserStatus = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user) 
//this outputs undefined when the request comes from the frontend but outputs the user when I //request from postman
  
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $set: { logged:true } },
        { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
    )
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

Comment: What HTTP request body encoding are you using when it works?

Comment: application/json; charset=utf-8

I set postman to sent raw json and this is on the header

Comment: There's a lot missing here. Where is your passport strategy? I gather you are using Mongo and likely mongoose. If that is the case then you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose as doing Auth right is hard.

Comment: I am using passport-local-mongoose already.
I solved the problem by removing the redirect on my login function.